# How to get function body, name, arguments and returning type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried to take from `information_schema.routines` and `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`. I cannot get or parse the arguments `information_schema.routines`. I think parsing the query of `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION` is a bad idea

Comment: There is an option to join information_schema.routines and SHOW CREATE FUNCTION and parse args from SHOW CREATE FUNCTION. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: information_schema.parameters table is the one you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name and body is in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES, as you know.

For function arguments, those are in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-parameters-table.html), which has a many-to-one relationship with the ROUTINES table. That is, a given function can have several arguments as well as a return value, so one function may correspond to multiple rows in the PARAMETERS table.

> The PARAMETERS table provides information about parameters for stored routines (stored procedures and stored functions), and about return values for stored functions. The PARAMETERS table does not include built-in SQL functions or user-defined functions (UDFs).